Calculating $p_{*}(\pi_1(E, e_0))$ for a pentagonal cover of $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$
I am studying covering spaces as part of my topology course and designed the following problem as a means to assess my current understanding of the topic.
I don't know how to include such a sophisticated diagram, so I have instead attached a piece of my scratchwork for the problem.
Note: My generators for the subgroup off to the right are merely my prediction based on the pattern I have observed in Hatcher's other examples. I have no idea if they are correct, and I would be grateful if anyone could revise them if they are mistaken.

Current Ideas: Every vertex in the covering space has a pair of incident $a$ and $b$ and another pair that is traveling away from it. I believe that Hatcher calls this property being an 2-oriented graph. Every vertex appears locally similar to the single vertex of $\mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1$.
Hatcher and my instructor suggest using Seifart Van Kampen for this particular problem. Furthermore, I am encouraged to choose my two open sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that every vertex in the covering space is included and the intersection $X_0$ is simply connected. I can understand that by making $X_0$ simply connected, I only have to consider $\pi_1(X_1) * \pi_1(X_2)$ without having to take a quotient of the group. What is the significance of including every vertex in the sets $X_1$ and $X_2$?
Assuming that my selections for $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correct for the application of the Seifart Van Kampen theorem, how do I go about calculating the fundamental groups for $X_1$ and $X_2$? The best I could imagine was that $X_1$ and $X_2$ were both somehow homotopic to the wedge sum of two paths. If I choose $X_1$ for example, I wanted to write $X_1 \simeq \mathbb S^1 \vee \mathbb S^1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1$ consisting of three paths $\gamma _ 1$, $gamma _ 2$, and $\gamma _ 3$ such that for $j : X_1 \simeq \mathbb S^1 \vee \mathbb S^1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1 \to X_1$, $j_{*}([\gamma_1]) = ab$, $j_*([\gamma_2])=a^2b^2$, and $j_*([\gamma_5])=b^5$. Is this approach correct for calculating $\pi_1 (X_1)$? Should I actually apply Seifart Van Kampen recursively to arrive at a solution?
Any pointers will be much appreciated.

You can use Proposition 1A.2 in Hatcher to find a free generating set of $\pi_1(E)$, in particular $E \simeq \bigvee_6 S^1$. It's not too hard to derive your generating set from the one you get by taking the spanning tree to be a 4-edge path with $e_0$ as midpoint.
